# pycharm: show only program output in console?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

In older versions of pycharm, the only things that appeared in the output window was the ones that I explicitly printed.

I recently updated it, and now it also prints everything that happens under the hood when the program runs (reading environment variables, setting path, running script, etc), so it's difficult to make out the actual output.

eg, a simple `print('hello world')` gives

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
import django; print('Django %s' % django.get_version())
sys.path.extend(['/Users/...', '/Users/...', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm', '/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev'])
if 'setup' in dir(django): django.setup()
import django_manage_shell; 
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
PyDev console: using IPython 6.2.1
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Django 2.2.6
/Users/.../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Backend MacOSX is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
runfile('/.../snippet.py', wdir='/Users/...')
hello world
```

How can I bring back the previous behavior?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what is printed? All it should print is the command that being executed, e.g.:

<path_to_interpreter> <path_to_script> <additional_params>

Comment: @AndreyResler: edited

Comment: That's because you have "Run with Python Console" option enabled in the run configuration used to execute the script. Disable it and you will revert to the original behavior. If you want to stick with Python console you can get rid of e.g. prints in Settings | Build | Console | Django Console.